# Can I use public key asymmetric encryption without certificates?

Tags: .net, cryptography, certificate, encryption-asymmetric

Are there other ways of using a public private key asymmetric encryption than using certificates?

The public/private parts should be easy to generate from managed .NET code.

Comment: @TimCooper: If you are going around changing the bodies of questions, please do it completely, and also clean up the titles.

Answer (score 0):

The `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class is a good starting point. Is that what you are looking for?